# Python using timedeltas for sum not working properly, cannot cast scalar

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

There's a lot of material out there on timedelta, but the suggestions are not working for my use case.

I have converted a column of time entries to timedelta like so:

```
Time: 04:19:03 to Time: 0 days 04:19:03
Time: 00:25:28 to Time: 0 days 00:25:28
```

I would like to sum up timedeltas based on parameters I have identified, like this:

```
groups = sample.groupby('user')['time']
flag = sample.groupby('user')['flag'].transform('max')
sample['time_new'] = np.select([flag.eq(0), flag.isin([1,2])], [groups.transform('sum'), groups.transform('max')])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

When I do this:

```
sample.loc[:,'time'] = pd.to_timedelta(sample['time'])
```

My data looks like this for reference:

```
User: 1 Flag: 0 Time: 04:00:03
User: 1 Flag: 0 Time: 00:25:00

User: 2 Flag: 1 Time: 04:20:00
User: 2 Flag: 1 Time: 01:26:00

User: 3 Flag: 2 Time: 1:00:01
User: 3 Flag: 2 Time: 14:00:02
```

And would like it to look like:

```
User: 1 Flag: 0 Time: 04:25:03
User: 1 Flag: 0 Time: 04:25:03

User: 2 Flag: 1 Time: 04:20:00
User: 2 Flag: 1 Time: 04:20:00

User: 3 Flag: 2 Time: 14:00:02
User: 3 Flag: 2 Time: 14:00:02
```

So, as you can see, only Flag 0 is added up because that's how my grouping parameter is defined. I need to convert to a time format that I can sum when flag is 0, otherwise it just takes the max value.

Comment: `groups = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str)).groupby(df['user'])`?

Comment: same scalar error, it is odd

Comment: Is it possible timedelta is an issue? Is there another way to sum time @ansev

Comment: try `np.where(flag.eq(0), groups.transform('sum'), groups.transform('max'))` instead `np.select` and `groups = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str)).groupby(df['user'])` I have had also the same problem with np.select yesterday